# How to have a list of Fields in django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-3.1

I have a models like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Article (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Users.User')
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()

    stars = [
        models.IntegerField(), # 0 stars
        models.IntegerField(), # 1 stars
        models.IntegerField(), # 2 stars
        models.IntegerField(), # 3 stars
        models.IntegerField(), # 4 stars
        models.IntegerField(), # 5 stars
    ]
```

but the problem is it the stars Fields won't be recognized in 000x_initials.py.
What I have to do?

I want to use it like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_data = request.post
    star = int(post_data['star'])
    article.stars[star] += 1
    article.save()
```

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL then you can use array field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: I'm not. I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

if you use POSTGRESQL as your DBMS you can use ArrayField:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
```

on your model:

```
stars = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), size=6)
```

that will create a 6 length array, you can also create multi dimensional arrays.

other ways try to create your custom field.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to POSTGRESQL this month. I will change my host plan next month. I still need a answer that works on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to store the stars, isn't it better to make it a single integer field and user can 1,2,...5 is stored based on what the user chooses, or even better, just 5 boolean fields.
Anyway, Answering your question, you can create another model having a foreign key to this model, like so:

```
class Article (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Users.User')
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()

class Stars (models.Model):
    star = models.IntegerField() #I would recommend boolean field instead
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way you can have many stars related to one article. You would have to handle it in the view a bit differently, like `Stars.objects.filter(article=article)` to get the stars for a specific article.

Comment: I don't want a long list of numbers. I want a list with length of 6 that keeps 6 number.

Comment: Sure, when an instance of `Stars` is created, check the count of stars related to the specific article and create the instance only if count is less than 6.